# Rotinas em PHP, usando return

Tags: php

No curso de PHP que estou fazendo, estamos agora em rotinas, e começamos a usar return, mas eu ainda não entendi muito bem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_css/estilo.css"/>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Curso de PHP - CursoemVideo.com</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>

<?php
    function soma($a,$b){
        return($a + $b);
    } 
      $x = 3;
      $y = 8;
      $res = soma($x,$y);
      echo"A soma entre $x e $y é = $res";

?>﻿ 
<br/>
<!--<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)" class="botao">VOLTAR</a>-->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Por que usar ele exatamente? Não era só criar um echo a + b e pronto? Não entendo muito bem a função do return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para um exemplo simples, como o dado na pergunta, de fato não faz tamanha diferença assim entre utilizar o `return` ou o `echo` diretamente no resultado. Porém, com a complexidade da sua aplicação aumentando, você entenderá mais facilmente. Vamos considerar primeiramente o exemplo utilizando `echo`:

```
function soma($a, $b)
{
    echo $a + $b;
}
```

Ao fazer:

```
$x = 3;
$y = 8;
$res = soma($x, $y);
echo "A soma entre $x e $y é = $res";
```

O seu resultado seria:

```
11
A soma entre 3 e 8 é =
```

Ou seja, o valor do resultado foi exibido antes. Já era esperado, pois o resultado da soma já é exibido na hora da chamada da função. Você pode pensar: ok, mas podemos fazer o seguinte:

```
$x = 3;
$y = 8;
echo "A soma entre $x e $y é = ", soma($x, $y);
```

O resultado será:

```
A soma entre 3 e 8 é = 11
```

Resolvido.

Para este exemplo, sim, mas agora utilize a função `soma` para calcular a seguinte expressão: 1+4+11. Você pode implementar outra função para isso:

```
function soma3($a, $b, $c)
{
    echo $a + $b + $c;
}

$x = 1;
$y = 4;
$z = 11;
echo "A soma entre $x, $y e $z é = ", soma3($x, $y, $z);
```

O resultado, de fato, será:

```
A soma entre 1, 4 e 11 é = 16
```

Mas e se precisar outras expressões? Por exemplo, para 4 ou 5 valores, você irá implementar uma função para cada? Matematicamente sabemos que para somar três valores nós podemos somar os dois primeiros e o resultado somar com o terceiro (propriedade associativa). Isto é, utilizando a função `soma`, mas agora com `return`:

```
function soma($a, $b)
{
    return $a + $b;
}
```

Para analisar a expressão 1+4+11, podemos fazer:

```
$x = 1;
$y = 4;
$z = 11;

$res1 = soma($x, $y); // Faz $res1 = $x + $y
$res2 = soma($res1, $z); // Faz $res2 = $res1 + $z

echo "A soma entre $x, $y e $z é = $res2";
```

Que o resultado será exatamente:

```
A soma entre 1, 4 e 11 é = 16
```

E se precisar para 4 valores, tipo 2+3+5+7? *No problems*.

```
$x = 2;
$y = 3;
$z = 5;
$w = 7;

$res1 = soma($x, $y); // $res1 = $x + $y
$res2 = soma($z, $w); // $res2 = $z + $w
$res3 = soma($res1, $res2); // $res3 = $res1 + $res2;

echo "A soma entre $x, $y, $z e $w é = $res3";
```

E o resultado será:

```
A soma entre 2, 3, 5 e 7 é = 17
```

Ou seja, com apenas uma função podemos analisar múltiplas expressões. Utilizar o `echo` não temos essa liberdade (reuso de código).

Comment: Obrigado Anderson, agora sim entendi!

Answer (score 2):

A utilidade do `return` é 'transferir' um valor de dentro de uma função para fora dela. Uma função retorna algum valor para que ele seja manipulado em outras partes do programa/script ou funciona como uma confirmação se a operação foi realizada com sucesso ou não.

> Por que usar ele exatamente? Não era só criar um echo a + b e pronto?

Depende do caso, agora imagine que o resultado de `soma()` precise ser ajustado em 10% fora função, o `echo $a + $b` faz sentido?